# phpinfo() gives wrong pcre information

Tags: php, pcre

My test file is very simple, 
        phpinfo();

When I run it under my apache, it gives me something like this, 
pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    5.0 13-Sep-2004

When I run it in command line, it gives me the right version number 6.6.

The php.ini is in /etc/php.ini.

How could I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Because apache and command line use different .ini files

Comment: phpinfo() gives you the PHP pcre library version, not the actual pcre version.

Comment: I could run the following two commands, 
php index.php  
and 
curl http://localhost/index.php
it gives me different information. 
index.php is the same, just phpinfo();

I couldnot figure out why. 
I have only one php.ini and it is pointed to /etc/php.ini.

Comment: by the way, I just want to fix the yii problem, "preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: this version of PCRE is not compiled with PCRE_UTF8 support at offset 0". I dont have package manager on my centos. So I have recompile everything.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by reinstalling php adding apache server location. Now the pcre info changed to what I expected.